# Forecast with lagged variable

Tags: python, time-series, regression, forecasting, feature-engineering

I have the following data on which i wants to predict(Model `CatboostRegressor`) and to add predicted value of a row to the next as lagged column value. For Example

**test_df**

| week_end_date | option | department | fp_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-21 | 0161910-BLUE-MAR BLUE | MENS_T_S_TOPS | 50 |
| 2023-05-28 | 0161910-BLUE-MAR BLUE | MENS_T_S_TOPS | 60 |
| 2023-05-21 | 0161569-PURPLE-LIL PURPLE | WMS_WVN_TOPS_DRESS | 10 |
| 2023-05-28 | 0161569-PURPLE-LIL PURPLE | WMS_WVN_TOPS_DRESS | 20 |

#### I want the results like this

| week_end_date | option | department | lagged_fpqty | predicted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-21 | 0161910-BLUE-MAR BLUE | MENS_T_S_TOPS | 0.0 | 55 |
| 2023-05-28 | 0161910-BLUE-MAR BLUE | MENS_T_S_TOPS | 55 | 80 |
| 2023-05-21 | 0161569-PURPLE-LIL PURPLE | WMS_WVN_TOPS_DRESS | 0.0 | 20 |
| 2023-05-28 | 0161569-PURPLE-LIL PURPLE | WMS_WVN_TOPS_DRESS | 20 | 23 |

#### I tried with

```
predictions = []
df2 = test_df[ow_features]
pred=0
for index in range(0,len(df2)):
    df2.at[index,'lagged_fpqty'] = pred
    pred = model.predict(df2.loc[index,:].values.reshape(1,-1))
    predictions.append(pred)
```